Best tool for proving that a (big) first order model is actually the model of some (big) first order theory.
I have to check that a (big: several hundreds axioms) first order logic theory is satisfiable.
There are various authomated provers for first order logic (e.g. Vampire) that could tell me if the theory is satisfiable or not. However, they all fail (they never terminate or run out of resources), due to the size of the theory.
I know of only two model finders for first order logic: Mace4 and Lean. They also fail due to the size.
Let me expand on the charachteristics of the logical theory: it is a foundational ontology. I cannot report it here in full, however it is very similar to any of the foundational ontologies found e.g. in this document (any of the chapters 2,3,4, to be precise).
The ontology signature is made from about 50 unary predicates, about 10 binary predicates, about 5 ternary predicates, and just one quaternary predicate.
A small minority of these are defined predicates which could in principle be removed by replacing them with their definient, the other are all primitives. For the rest equality is used, but no algebraic operations.
The ontology has about 200 axioms, which are of various types.
Many axioms are simple subsumption, disjointedness, and domain/range axioms, i.e. axioms of type (free variables are universally quantified):
$$A(x) \Rightarrow B(x)$$
$$B(x) \Rightarrow \neg C(x)$$
$$E(x,y,z) \Rightarrow F(x) \land G(y) \land H(z)$$
respectively, where $A$ to $H$ are appropriate predicate symbols.
Equality is used and there are some functionality declarations e.g.:
$$\phi(x,y) \Rightarrow x = y$$
where $\phi$ is a conjunction of unary and binary predicates.
There are also more complex axioms, one type of axioms that are especially problematic are non-emptiness of classes and existential rules, i.e.
$$\exists x A(x)$$
$$\phi(\bf{x},\bf{y}) \Rightarrow \exists \bf{z} (\psi(\bf{z}, \bf{y}))$$
where $A$ is an appropriate predicate, and $\phi$ and $\psi$ are conjunctions of atomic predicates and the variables in bold stand for (short) lists of variables. There are about >30 existential rules.
There are also some axioms in which a disjunction is present in the consequent of an entailment
There is also a small number of most complex axioms, which have multiple nested quantifiers: consider e.g. the definition of mereological sum from Wikipedia
$$U(x,y) \Rightarrow \exists z \forall v (O(v,z) \Leftarrow \Rightarrow (O(v,x) \land O(v,y)))$$
As said, understandably, the tools I know fail to find a model.
Nevertheless, I think I can produce an explicit model for the theory. Lets assume that we specify the model as a list of constants, followed by a list of true atomic statements, with the convention that non-explicitely stated facts are false. Then the model contains about 25 constants and about 200 statements. It would look like this:
$constants$ (all different): $c1, c2, ..., c25$
$relations: A(c1), A(c2), B(c1), ..., P(c1, c4, c16), ..., Z(c22,c23,c24,c35)$
Now, due to the size of the model and of the number of axioms, I am not actually sure the model is a model, therefore a model checking tool would be quite helpful and would prove that the theory is consistent, or that I was wrong.
The issue is I don't know of any such model checking tool for first order logic, if any exists.
Up to today, the approach I followed consisted in hammering the model into a complete theory containing apprpriate statements and then asking to a prover if all the axioms of the target theory are entailed by the 'theorified' model. E.g., suppose that I want to prove satisfability of the simple theory (with just one binary predicate, $P$)
$$\forall x,y,z . P(x,y) \land P(y,z) \Rightarrow P(x,z)$$
I would like to use a tool that allows me to specify a formal model using the signature of the theory, say:
$constants$ (all different)$: a,b $ 
$relations: P(a,b), P(b,a), P(a,a), P(b,b)$
and that checks if this model is actually a model of the theory. As of now I would 'theorify' the model into the theory:
$$\forall x . (x=a) \lor (x=b)$$
$$a\neq b$$
$$\forall x,y . P(x,y) \Leftrightarrow ((x=a \land y=b)\lor(x=b \land y=a)\lor(x=a \land y=a)\lor(x=b \land y=b))$$
And then ask Vampire if the theorified model entails the transitivity axiom. Not only this is incredible laborious if you have a big model/theory/signature, sometimes Vampire (and any other prover, actually) is not even able to prove an obvious entailment (the entailment is obvious if checking case-by-case, Vampires tries its skolemization resolution algorithm which does not realize this possibility of checking case-by-case).
In summary, my question is:
Are there any model checker tool out there that can help me? Alternatively, is there a simpler way (or even more complex but more performing way) than my current approach to check if a model is actually a model for some first order theory?

Welcome to Math.SE. Lots of important context is missing here. You write: I (think I) can produce an explicit model for the theory. You should share more about the structure that you found that you believe to be a model. Is it finite? If so, how big is it? If not, then does it have some nice presentation? How complicated are the axioms you're considering? Are they algebraic? Or do they have many quantifier alterations? (And note that Mace4 could not have helped you anyway if all models of your theory are infinite)

I agree with needing more context, more specifically a little bit about what the theory is and where it comes from. I also think this question is a good fit for the Proof Assistants Stack Exchange, but 1) the context issue should be resolved before the question is moved not after (if it is moved at all), 2) I think this question is on topic in both Stack Exchanges.

Depending on the size of your finite models, maybe an approach based on matrices (well, tensors, since your relations might not be binary) might work, but if you want to work with relations of, say, arity 20 on a model of 1000 elements, then this will fail (you would have to work with multidimensional arrays with $1000^{20}=2^{200}$ elements). Lots of binary relations, around 1000 elements, that's something e.g. numpy might handle (don't ask me to write the code though). In any event, simplifying the formulas as much as possible first might help.

@Z.A.K., thank you for your inputs. I have modified the question adding additional context as suggested. Is it better now?

@GregNisbet thank you for your inputs, I have cited a document with similar theories and have expanded upon the main charachteristics of the theory.

@tomasz , thankyou for your input. The model is actually relatively simple. In fact, it appears easy to check manually, though extremely laborious and error-prone. For this reason I wanted to know if a tool exist that does it for me, before developing one myself.

@kataph: Yes, I think it's answerable now. Accordingly, I voted to reopen, but it'll take some time for that to happen. Preliminarily, given that your model is finite and not too large, but the set of laws to check is quite large, I think a custom Python script that exhaustively verifies your axioms or stops upon finding a counterexample is a possible option.

@GregNisbet Since the question has been reopened could it be possible to move it also in the Proof Assistants Stack Exchange?

I flagged the moderators and requested to move it.

@GregNisbet Thanks!
